# How can I search a C# collection

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, and I am writing a new process that will load data from an excel sheet into a database. I have a table in the database that hold the mapping and validation details. This is inserted into a collection of class in the same method.

Currently I am stuck and would be glad if one of you can help me.

I have a following variables that holds the names of heading from an Excel sheet.

```
List<string> fileColumnNames = new List<string>();
```

Lets say the above two column names of the file store in the above collection are "**EOM Date**" and "**Client Id**"

Now a collection `class TableColumnDetails()` has following values

> File_Name    DB_COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE
>
> EOM Date     business_date      date
>
> Client Id    client_id          number
>
> Order Type   order_no           number

How do I compare "**EOM Date**" and "**Client Id**" in the string list `fileColumnNames` with that of the class collection, `TableColumnDetails()`?

For example, if "**EOM Date**" and "**EOM Date**" matches how do I get the `DB_COLUMN_NAME and DATA_TYPE`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not entirely sure but Dictionary might be a useful container for you

Comment: Excels are like tables- why not keep them that way? Could use `OleDb` to read the Excel into a `DataTable` and then send the `DataTable` to your database. That should get rid of the need for enumeration

Answer (score 1):

The best approach will be to convert the list of "TableColumnDetails" into a dictionary with key as "File_Name" and value as the class object itself

```
var dict = listOfTableColumnDetails.OrderBy(x=>x.File_Name).ToDictionary(x=>x, x=>x.ToList().FirstOrDefault());

//dict[fileColumnNames[0]] should give you the TableColumnDetails associated to the first file name.
```